# How do I remove a marker in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 3, you could randomly place markers, and then if you wanted to remove them, you just clicked back on it and selected remove marker.

I know I have set markers before now in Fallout 4, and removed them. But I have set a marker that I can not seem to remove!

What is the proper way to remove a marker you place somewhere on the map? Especially when its on a place on your map (that you have or haven't found yet)?

Comment: On the PC at least when you try to place a marker in a new place it gives you the option to remove any existing markers instead

Comment: I do wish you could leave more than one marker, and could leave notes on the markers... **Safe** everywhere there's a safe I wasn't able to crack!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once a custom marker has been placed, you can remove it by simply attempting to place another marker.

When you opt to place a second marker, a warning message will display, telling you you have already placed a custom marker.

You will be given the option to move the marker, or outright remove it.

As DCShannon points out, the cursor is fond of snapping to nearby markers, so it would be a good idea to ensure you move the cursor to a clearing to bring up the remove marker option.

Comment: +1, this is correct. I've had some problems with not being able to remove the marker because the cursor is super sticky and tries to snap to locations. Might help to suggest finding an open, empty part of the map to click on. Zooming in can help with this.

Comment: If memory serves right, this is the same way markers worked in Skyrim (also a recent Bethesda title), so I suspect that they just ported the marker system over from Skyrim.

Comment: One the xbox one I don't think you are given the option to outright remove it, unless you zoom to an area it doesn't snap to. Was looking more to fully remove them than make another. But zooming into a particular empty area and trying to place a marker gives you the option. FO3 let you just click on an existing one to remove.

Answer (score 9):

To remove a marker on Xbox One:

- Open your Pipboy by pressing <kbd>B</kbd>.
- Use <kbd>RT</kbd> or <kbd>LT</kbd> to select the "Map" tab.
- Move your left joystick to move the cursor to an open area of the map.
- Press <kbd>A</kbd>. You should be prompted with a dialog box asking if you want to move the current marker or remove it. Select "Remove Marker".

Here's a YouTube video I found that shows the process in action: